# what's the difference between DLDFLAGS and LDFLAGS

Tags: gcc, linker, makefile, ldflags

A quick question. I found both "DLDFLAGS" and "LDFLAGS" in a sample Makefile. The compiler used is gcc. It looks like they are both used for linkers. I'm wondering what's the difference between them.

Comment: It could be for the dynamic linker flags, I guess. I couldn't find precise information online. Can you tell us what the value of `DLDFLAGS` is?

Answer (score 10):

`LDFLAGS` is normally set to contain options that are passed through to the linker (so may include required libraries). Together with `CFLAGS`, these are often set as part of a developers environment variables and `make` will know about them so will actively look to see if they're set and pass them through to the compiler.

For example, if I set `CFLAGS` in my environment to `-O2 -Wall`, then if I type `make hello` with no Makefile, make will automatically invoke the compiler as `gcc -O2 -Wall hello.c -o hello.o`. Then it'll invoke the linker in a similar way, adding the flags in `LDFLAGS` to the command line.

Makefiles can explicitly override both `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`.

`DLDFLAGS` on the other hand is not a well known/defined variable, so it's likely to be specific to that particular Makefile. You'd have to read the Makefile to find out how it's used. It may, for example, define linker flags to use if `LDFLAGS` is set - read the Makefile to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `DLDFLAGS` just a precompiler flag that defines macro named "LDFLAGS"?

From gcc manual:

> -D name
>
> ```
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1
> ```